# Login not redirecting to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I created a simple login form with username and password. My login is not redirecting to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL link which should redirect to the home page. I tried several credentials from the admin side(which I got from signing up)

Urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from jobs import views as jobs_views      #from the job application it is gonna import views
from users import views as users_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
```

path('', jobs_views.home, name='home_page'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'login.html'), name= 'login'),]

Login.html(only added relevant code):

```
<section class="site-section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <!-- DEBUG -->
                      {% for field in form %}
                          {% if field.errors %}{{ field.html_name }}: {{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
            
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h2 class="mb-4">Log In To JobBoard</h2>
              <form class="p-4 border rounded", submit= 'POST'>
  
                <div class="row form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                    <label class="text-black" for="fname">Username</label>
                    {{ form.username }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group mb-4">
                  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                    <label class="text-black" for="fname">Password</label>
                    {{ form.password }}
                  </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="row form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn px-4 btn-primary text-white">
                  </div>
                </div>
  
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

settins.py(only added relevant code):

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home_page'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

I tried putting to display errors but did not recieved any:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <!-- DEBUG -->
                      {% for field in form %}
                          {% if field.errors %}{{ field.html_name }}: {{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

Comment: there is nothing on /home_page. I tried leaving it blank '' but did not work

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: no only the url changes to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?username=username&password=password"